# What is wrong with my attempt at Spring quickstart?

Tags: java, spring, maven

So I am trying out the very very simple spring quickstart. You can find it [here](https://spring.io/quickstart).

I have have java 1.8 installed, but am downloading Java 11 in the mean time from the suggested location (AdoptOpenJDK) just to be sure that isn't the problem.

I followed all the instructions, but when running the project, I get... nothing...

```
~/spring/demo$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)

~/spring/demo$ ./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

It has been like this for 30 minutes while I've been typing out this question.  There are no logs or anything to suggest what might be wrong.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I am now getting a zip error within maven.  I am still using java 1.8

```
~/spring/demo$ ./mvnw spring-boot:run
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.unzip(Installer.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trenin , Please check whether you have 7Zip/Winzip Software because during startup it looks for these to unzip certain dependencies that it downloads .

Comment: Installed 7zip.  No luck.  I will work on installing java 11 when I have more time and try again.